# How to use single activity(class) and single layout(xml) to show different data based on item selection in recycler view

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create an app which shows the list of cities. And when clicked it should show brief detail of that city. I have created list using recyclerview. I am thinking to add 100 cities in app, I don't wanna create 100 class files for cities. I want to use single class file and a single layout to show different data based on selection.

ex: to show the list I have used Main.class, main.xml, adapter.class
    if an item is selected, it should call Next.class(and next.xml).
    I want Next.class to pass different data to next.xml based on the selection          of item in Main.class

Is there a way to do that. I am new to android app development, so it would be great if you guys help me out with a very brief explanation and code.
                                             Thank You.

Comment: use one activity for listview and other activity for description ....

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/zhaozhentao/InboxLayout

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Activity file(CityDetailsActivity.java) with one xml to display city details
Inside OnItemClickListener of RecyclerView call the CityDetailsActivity using intent.

Comment: I know how to call same activity for each selection. But how can I pass different data(text,image) to xml file, based on selection.

Comment: You can use Bundle to send data(image, text) in your second Activity.
For sending image:
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap image= imageView.getDrawingCache();
 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
extras.put("text", getText().toString());
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);

//And get same using getIntent() 
Let me know if you still have doubts.

Comment: can you post your code here and what you want to achieve ?It will make things clear.

Comment: Thanx for help. I Solved. I just used the position of RecyclerView in Main.java and passed it to switch case of Next.java(using Bundle).

Comment: Great,  Gud luck!

Comment: Thats ok. & I might need your help, for designing the layouts.